# Oh no! Something has gone wrong. The system can't recover

Tags: boot, bluetooth, internet

While I was in Uni class I wanted to restart my laptop after finishing an assignment. After it booted up it had It said: "Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator".

I looked up the problem and most of them said to switch to `tty` to update and upgrade some packages. But I've noticed that after I log in it says that it failed to connect to a Ubuntu changelog website and that I should check my Internet connection. But I have no idea about this, because I'm relatively new to using Ubuntu let alone Linux.

Something I also noticed noticed is when my laptop boots before showing the oh no screen it says

```
 "/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 730353/62480384 files, 33439878/249919744 blocks
4.905499] Bluetooth: hci0: sending Intel patch command (0xfc8e) failed (-71) 4.905588] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[
[
[
4.905625] Bluetooth: hci0: Exiting manufacturer mode failed (-19)
" and than this flashes up for a second "/dev/numeOn1p2: clean, 730353/62480384 files, 33439878/249919744 blocks
[
[
[
4.905499] Bluetooth: hci0: sending Intel patch command (OxfcBe) failed (-71 4.905588] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
4.905625] Bluetooth: hci0: Exiting manufacturer mode failed (-19)
[ 8.8864811 =====
[
8.886496] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in build/linux-hue-6.5-q7N20T/1 inux-hue-6.5-6.5.0/drivers/gpu/drm/and/andgpu/../pn/powerplay/hungr/processpptab
les.c:929:40
[
[
8.886514] index 1 is out of range for type 'UCHAR [1]'
8.894046]=================================================================
```

Maybe this will give some clarity.

Answer (score -1):

From the error, seems it could be bluetooth driver related issue.

If your system is coming up after this error, try disabling bluetooth and see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: How do I do that? in the tty?